# This engine did not provide a list of tried templates

Tags: python, django

Wup, I'm trying to deploy a localhost web using Django but I get the following error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
templates/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.1.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
```

I was looking tutorials and docs but I didn't found the answer.

Here is my settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
DEBUG = True
ROOT_URLCONF = 'FortyTwop.urls'
SECRET_KEY = 'This is a secret key'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

also urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

And views.py

```
from email import message
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

My path tree:

```
.
├── FortyTwop
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── manage.py
```

What Im doing bad or what I didn't have in the settings?, this project is just for test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`templates/` is the base path you've configured in the settings, so you'll want

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Furthermore, `TEMPLATE_DIRS` hasn't been a thing since Django 1.8 or so, and you're on Django 4.x. See [these instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings).

Comment: Same error :( "django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html"

Comment: @Cerbero Please paste your updated `TEMPLATES` configuration into your original question.

Comment: Also I removed the TEMPLATE_DIRS var from settings.py

Comment: Yes, but you were supposed to replace it with a  `TEMPLATES` configuration.

Comment: Already updated in original question

Comment: I don't see your updated `TEMPLATES` configuration in your question. If you don't have a `TEMPLATES` configuration, Django won't look in an arbitrary `templates/` directory. The link in my answer shows you how to port a `TEMPLATE_DIRS` configuration into `TEMPLATES`.

Comment: Okay, now I follow the link and add the TEMPLATES config, but still the same error

Comment: @Cerbero The `DIRS` you've added isn't the same as you had before. `os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),` is not `'templates',`.